# How to identify android phone flip 180 degrees

Tags: android, android-sensors, flip

I need to identify is mobile display faced upside or downside. So how can do that? In the start phone display upside then it down side(display to earth and sky). not rotating the screen by fliping the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Register for sensor `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`. In the `onSensorChanged`

```
if (event.values[2] > 0)
{
    // screen up
}
else
{
    // screen down
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getRotation` method :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation

It will return either of 4 options : `ROTATION_0`, `ROTATION_90`, `ROTATION_180`, `ROTATION_270`

Comment: I need flip of the device. That mean rotae the phone through x axis.